# How to raise exceptions in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, exception

I'm asking for Delphi native, not Prism(net).

This is my code:

```
raise Exception.Create('some test');
```

Undeclared identifier "Exception".

Where's the problem, how do I throw/raise exceptions?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The exception class "Exception" is declared in the unit SysUtils. So you must add "SysUtils" to your uses-clause.

```
uses
  SysUtils;

procedure RaiseMyException;
begin
  raise Exception.Create('Hallo World!');
end;
```

Comment: For future reference, "undeclared identifier" errors can frequently be solved by searching the included source code for the identifier you're interested in. That will tell you where it's declared, and it might also provide examples of how to use it.

Comment: In D2006+ (maybe 2005?) you can use the "Refactoring -> Find Unit" option from the right-click menu to add the required unit to your uses clause.

Comment: Gerry - fabulous added tip there!... I'm embarrassed to say, I've never noticed that feature.  Very cool. : )

Answer (score 13):

Remember to add `SysUtils` to your `uses` units.

I also suggest below a nice way to keep track of categories, formats of messages and meaning of exception:

```
Type TMyException=class
public
  class procedure RaiseError1(param:integer);
  class procedure RaiseError2(param1,param2:integer);
  class procedure RaiseError3(param:string);
end;

implementation

class procedure TMyException.RaiseError1(param:integer);
begin
  raise Exception.create(format('This is an exception with param %d',[param]));
end;

//declare here other RaiseErrorX
```

A simple way of using this is:

```
TMyException.RaiseError1(123);
```

Comment: there is already `Exception.CreateFmt` which supports Format with an array of const

Comment: @mjn, but it makes the life of the clients (the code that uses `TMyException`) a lot easier - just pass the parameters and the rest will be done in `TMyException`.

Comment: @EdwinYip what I mean is that `raise Exception.create(format('This is an exception with param %d',[param]));` can be shortened to `raise Exception.CreateFmt('This is an exception with param %d',[param]);` which does the same with less keystrokes

Answer (score 7):

You may need to add sysutils to the uses clause, it is not built in and is optional according to Delphi in a nutshell.

Answer (score 6):

You are using SysUtils aren't you?  Exception is declared in there IIRC.